# How to validate one field based on the other field using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table

```
<table>
  <tr class ="entry1">
  <td class = "my_cell" name ="point" >
  <td class = "my_cell" name ="distance1" >
   <td class = "my_cell" name ="distance2" >
   </tr>

   <tr class ="entry2">
  <td class = "my_cell" name ="point" >
  <td class = "my_cell" name ="distance1" >
   <td class = "my_cell" name ="distance2" >
   </tr>

</table>
```

If any of the fields with the name "distance1" or "distance2" is filled then the corresponding text box in the same row (not in the other row)with the name "point" should be filled ,if not then a error message should be printed.

If the text field with the name "point" is filled then the corresponding test boxes "distance1" or "distance2" in the same not in the other row) row should be filled or a error message must be printed

Comment: What is your question? It seems you are looking for code. Rather, you might want to show what you have so that we can help where you get stuck.

Comment: I have a table
<table>
  <tr class ="entry1">
  <td class = "my_cell" name ="point" >
  <td class = "my_cell" name ="distance1" >
   <td class = "my_cell" name ="distance2" >
   </tr>
   
   <tr class ="entry2">
  <td class = "my_cell" name ="point" >
  <td class = "my_cell" name ="distance1" >
   <td class = "my_cell" name ="distance2" >
   </tr>

</table>

Comment: this part in the question is not displaying ,please consider this example for the above question

Comment: Vinay, I fixed the code formatting for you. You need to indent code blocks with 4 spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: thanks , I will make use of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('input[name=distance1], input[name=distance2]').change(function() {
    if (this.value != "") {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('[name=point]').val(filling); //whatever the value should be
    } else {
        // show error message
    }
});
```

It isn't flawless, you probably want a better check than this.value.

After the edit (I assumed inputs, now it's less dynamic):

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
     var row = $(this);
     if (row.find('[name=distance1]').text() != "" || row.find('[name=distance1]').text() != "") {
          row.find('[name=point]').text(filling); //whatever you want to set
     } else {
          // show error message
     }
});
```

This runs once, and you need something similar for the point-exception. But it's not specific enough to create it now.

Comment: I kinda assumed you had inputs which could, name on a td is a bit strange. After the edit I think you want something else.. give me a min.